# HTTPS connection closed after SSL handshake with no exception

Tags: python, ssl, sentry, urllib3

I'm using a library (sentry.io observer) that should connect to a remote server via https and upload some data. I do not control the server, but I can see that no data is uploaded. I set the urllib logger level to debug and I see two log messages

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): <server_url>:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (2): <server_url>:443
```

but no exception is thrown. I used wireshark to sniff packets and I see two SSL handshakes are executed, but the FIN packet is sent right after server finishes the handshake. Packets exchange looks like:

```
< - client sends message
> - server sends message

< TCP handshake [syn, syn ack, ack]
< Client hello
> Server hello, certificate, server key exchange, server hello done
< Client key exchange, change cipher spec, finished
> New session ticket, change cipher spec, finished
< TCP connection termination [fin ack, fin ack, ack]
```

This packet exchange is done twice, as urllib tries to connect to the remote server twice. The server certificate is valid, but the connection is cancelled by client. I set the library and urllib loggers to debug, but no error messages or anything that could help me narrow the issue down appears.

The issue only appears when requests are done from docker (based on centos 7), but when launching the app on ubuntu host it works fine, connection is established and data is uploaded. What could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: *"I'm using a library ..."* - which means it could be a problem with this unknown library. Or maybe not. It would be useful if you could narrow down the problem by using libraries like `requests` (i.e. happens here too or not). Also it is not clear from your output who closes the connection, i.e. who sends the first FIN - client or server? And there are really no TLS alerts on the wire before the close, i.e. no SSL shutdown done?

Comment: I've updated the question. The connection is closed by client and there are really no more packets than during regular TLS handshake. It just looks like after handshake the client is closing connection instead of sending data